# How to make Google piechart responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization, pie-chart

I have a **Google pie chart** which works fine but it is not responsive, how to make it responsive?

---

Here is a `<div>` on which i'm forming piechart.

```
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/79ffvayr/)** of my code.

Comment: Top google response for "Google Chart Responsive" https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA

Comment: @DanielShillcock, but it is for bar chart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution, using [throttledresize.js](https://rawgit.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/master/jquery.throttledresize.js).

### 1) Put your `div id="chart_div"` in a parent `div`

```
<div id="chart_wrap">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

---

### 2) Style these divs

```
#chart_wrap {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#chart_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

*Note: Adapt the CSS to your needs.*

---

### 3) Add this code at the end of your JS

```
$(window).on("throttledresize", function (event) {
    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    };

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
    drawChart(data, options);
});
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opoqaq14/)

Answer (score 2):

**Easiest method in the world:**

```
var options = {'width':'auto', 'height':'auto'};
```